# Wirelessly connecting a USB device with a computer

Tags: usb, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

I want to wirelessly connect a USB device to a PC. So for example, let's assume I have a usb mouse, a usb web cam, etc.. I want to connect that device to some sort of hub that wirelessly transfers the data to a PC.

I am aware of WUSB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_USB 
but seems that it is no longer produced. I could not find any devices for sale. I only came across this and it is no longer available: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000UU46W8/?tag=stackoverfl08-20](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000UU46W8)

I thought about the following:

1. connect USB device to an Arduino
2. wirelessly transfer the data from the Arduino to the PC
3. Somehow make the PC treat this incoming signal as a newly plugged in USB device

But I am not sure if this solution would even work.

I also thought about buying a wireless USB mouse or keyboard, breaking it, and using parts from it, but I am not sure if this will work either.

So the question is, does anyone have any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The native wireless USB hubs have died from natural causes several years ago. An alternative would be the "USB over TCP-IP" projects, [check this one](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/).